# Inspecting at an Objects Sync Block Index

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, locking, compact-framework, clr

I was wondering if there is anyway in C# to look at an object's Sync Block Index or even the Sync Block itself?

In Windows CE and .NET Compact Framework 3.5 I'm seeing an intermittent defect where I get an ArgumentException when calling `Monitor.Exit()` (I actually use a `lock` but it gets thrown on the compiled `Monitor.Exit()`). I have a feeling threads are getting aborted at some point and I'd like to catch the exception and check the state of the lock object's sync block.

Comment: Grasping at straws here: Create a VS application and add a reference to this Sync Block executable, then start exploring what all it has exposed. I don't know what the Sync Block is, though. Got a link for a definition?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx#S3. Basically every object that is created has an Object Overhead Field associated with it. This field contains a pointer to the Type object for this object and also a SyncBlock index. The CLR has an array of SyncBlocks and on Monitor.Enter() the object's SyncBlock Index is associated with one of these SyncBlocks. Each of these SyncBlocks contains the kernal object, owning thread's ID, Recursion Count, and a Waiting Threads Count. See Chapter 29, "Hybrid Thread Synchronization" in the book CLR via C# (3rd ed).